# Enterprise application development-RMI and EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, rmi

I am new to enterprise applications. Just started to learn EJB. I know RMI well. Can anyone map RMI with EJB to understand the basic strongly else give some links/books to clearly understand EJB basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compared to EJB, RMI is a "small" specification pertaining to remote invocation. EJB is much larger and actually includes RMI. The Wikipedia article about [Enterprise JavaBean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBean) is a must read.

I would recommend you also read [Mastering Enterprise JavaBeans 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471785415) by Sriganesh et al.